# HttpCalloutMock for string response

Tags: rest-api, httpcalloutmock

The response from my API call is a csv from a url:
UniCode;Purchased Date;City
12343;12/04/2000;London
12344;12/04/2003;London

How can I create a HttpCalloutMock and setBody to replicate that? I keep getting unexpected character errors..

I tried this:

```java
public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    //comment
    //System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());
    // Create a fake response
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setBody('{"UniCode;Purchased Date;City\\n12343;12/04/2000;London\\n12344;12/04/2003;London"}');
            
    res.setStatusCode(200);
    return res;
}
```

and got this error:

> USER_DEBUG [161]|DEBUG|An exception occurred: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value at [line:1, column:105]

Comment: It could be a simple issue of needing to escape single quotes, but we'll be able to give you a more tailored answer if you [edit] your question to include the mock class, the portion of the class you're testing that handles the response, and the full error message (verbatim, with stack trace).

Comment: @DerekF Here, added. Please help if any ideas

Answer (score 0):

There's a discrepancy between what you're saying and what you're doing.

You're working with *semicolon* separated value data
Your mock class is trying to pass it as JSON

SSV != JSON, so that's a problem.

You should

- use `text/csv` for the content type (or maybe `text/plain`)
- and then remove the curly braces and double quotes from your response body

If there are additional problems, then you need to share more of your code (like the part of the class that uses this httpresponse data that I asked for in the comments).